# Trying to open .php page when clicking on asp button

Tags: c#, php, asp.net

I am trying to integrate php pages with .net web forms.
I have just copied .php web page and paste into .net web application

Here is .net code:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
```

and Code Behind is

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Server.Transfer("register.php");
}
```

but it gives an Exception Given Below

> Server Error in '/' Application. No http handler was found for request
>   type 'POST'
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: No http handler was found
>   for request type 'POST'
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 17:         protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs
>   e) Line 18:         { Line 19:
>   Server.Transfer("register.php"); Line 20:             Line 21:
>   }
>
> Source File: c:\Users\Vishal\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\TestHomePage\test3\WebForm2.aspx.cs    Line: 19
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): No http handler was found for request
>   type 'POST']
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.MapIntegratedHttpHandler(HttpContext
>   context, String requestType, VirtualPath path, String pathTranslated,
>   Boolean useAppConfig, Boolean convertNativeStaticFileModule) +898
>   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(String path, TextWriter writer,
>   Boolean preserveForm) +464
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Error executing child request for
>   register.php.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/caxa892w(v=vs.110).aspx (the Server.Transfer docs):

> "The page transferred to should be another .aspx page. For instance, a
>   transfer to an .asp or .asmx page is not valid."

Try `Response.Redirect("register.php");` instead. This will cause a browser redirect to the PHP page. What you're doing currently is basically asking the .NET framework to execute some PHP code.

Also, you need to ensure you've installed the PHP engine on the server and it's all properly registered with IIS, otherwise the PHP page won't execute.

Background: PHP and ASP.NET are two completely different frameworks / languages. It's not clear if this is your aim, but it's worth noting that you can't expect to do an internal transfer from one to the other preserving all your session data etc etc, they run in entirely separate contexts. You can redirect from one to the other as I've suggested, but the scripts will not function as though they were a single application unless you do a lot of fudging behind the scenes.

Depending how much PHP / .NET you've got it might be easier to just rewrite one of the languages into the other one in order to integrate them, or define some formal APIs to allow them to exchange data in an orderly fashion.

Comment: but these two projects are in same solution but on different Application , whenever i used above method then That "Page Not found " Error Appears.

Comment: I gave the filename as a simple example but if it's not in the same folder in the website you'll need to give a more specific path or a full URL. Page Not Found just means the PHP file wasn't where you specified. I don't know where it really is in your IIS structure, so you need to work that out. But the principle is the same.

Comment: Ok ,Thank You Very Much , I Will Try Definitely